# Change Illustrator artboard grid from 8x8 to 10x10?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Only 8x8?

How do I make the artboard from 8x8 grid to a 10x10 grid?

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to do this in `preferences -> guides and grids`

[image]

Comment: If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark next to this post to set it as the accepted answer.